# Session Variables in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, session, magento-1.9

I am trying to create a session variable that I can pass to the checkout in Magento 1.9.

Its basically to pass coupons automatically to the checkout for certain pages, I have the add coupon working but can't seem to pass a coupon code correctly.

I have tried the following:

Simply add `?coupon_code=$coupon` to the string, but this seems to get stripped possibly due to url rewrites for languages.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name"=>"frontend"));     //load session variables 
$session->setData("data", $coupon); //save your data in custom session variable
```

but when I try to get this session in the cart it fails to find anything.

Can someone point me in the right direction for what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please use 'checkout/session' instead of core/session.

Comment: Thank you very much, its passing correctly now (now I just need to auto apply it!)

Answer (score 0):

Please use 'checkout/session' instead of core/session